# Send an http delete request

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest, http-delete

I need to how I can send an http delete request, I've implemented the code below

```
- (void) deleteSyncRequestWithURL:(NSString *) url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];  
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] retain];    
}
```

But I've got a 404 status.

Does anyone know what I'm missing??

P.S: I'm using xcode 3.2.3, simulator 4.0

Comment: 404 is "document not found" - the url you're asking to be deleted doesn't exist.

Comment: but I did that with other client and it works

Comment: Which would mean that your other client has deleted the resource, so it no longer exists?

Comment: :D, no, it's not that, well, I found the error I'm using h t t p://www .restOfMyUrl I should use h t t p://restOfMyUrl, it's working now, thx :))

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your Delete request is being issued correctly, but the server is choosing to respond with a 404 - document not found error.

Do you have control over the server application too?  Are you sure the server has a resource at that URL that responds to a Delete request?

If you are suspicious of the Delete request being made - I would use an HTTP proxy to examine the request directly, you can then compare to your other client.  I would use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (on the Mac).  If the other client is on a PC, you could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is excellent.

Comment: I found the error I'm using h t t p://www .restOfMyUrl I should use h t t p://restOfMyUrl, it's working now, thx :))

Comment: Well as Marc B and I said - do you have a resource at the URL? The answer was no because your URL was wrong.  I find HTTP proxy tools like Wireshark and Fiddler to be essential tools when writing software that uses HTTP.  Using such tools, you could easily see that the application had been sent to the wrong URL.